# prettyPhoto и видео из вконтакте

Tags: php, iframe, вконтакте

Здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема: решил поставить на сайте плагин prettyPhoto который открывает видео в модальном окне, но не тут то было, во первых код видео из вконтакте храниться в базе в своем начальном виде: `<iframe src="http://vkontakte.ru/video_ext.php?....</iframe>` а для того чтоб работал скрипт prettyPhoto необходимо иметь просто адрес (http://vkontakte.ru/video_ext.php?....) а также чтоб в этом адресе была запись "&iframe=true".
Т.е если ставить видео ручками то необходимо проделать вышеупомянутые операции. Ну а когда идет вывод из базы подобного не сделать. Можете посоветовать как это обойти, либо есть рабочие скрипты под видео вконтакте, либо возможно как-то модифицировать скрипт prettyPhoto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как чем?! А `substr`? А регулярные выражения?

Comment: Ну и конкатениция для добавления дополнительного параметра )

Comment: Решил проблему, спасибо

Comment: Действительно рад за тебя, что удалось понять все подсказки и решить проблему! Молодец!

Answer (score 3):

> Ну а когда идет вывод из базы
> подобного не сделать.

По-моему, именно тогда это и нужно делать..

Comment: Поподробней, пожалуйста.

Comment: Почему вы написали, что этого не сделать ?

Comment: Потому что я не знаю, чем можно "вычленить" из строки только часть адреса и добавить туда другой отрывок.